# Given General Solution

Tags: calculus

Not quite sure where to start with this one. It's asking for an ODE with constant coefficients. Any advice one where to at least start?

Thanks!

Comment: It also might be helpful to note that $\cos^2 x = \frac{1}{2} \cos (2 x)+\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Expressing in terms of complex exponentials and expanding, $(x + \cos(x))\cos(x)$
has terms in $e^{rx}$ for $r = 0, 2i, -2i$ and $x e^{rx}$ for $r = i$ and $-i$.
Thus $0$ and $\pm 2i$ are roots, and $\pm i$ a double root, of the characteristic polynomial of the linear differential equation.  The polynomial of least degree with these roots is $r (r-i)^2(r+i)^2 (r-2i)(r+2i) = r^7 + 6 r^5 + 9 r^3 + 4 r$.
Thus the differential equation could be
$$ y^{(7)} + 6 y^{(5)} + 9 y^{(3)} + 4 y' = 0$$

Comment: Thank you for the help. I guess I am a bit lost still. How do you go about determining those as the roots? If you don't mind expanding a bit.

Comment: @PCollins Use the formula $\cos (x) = \frac 12 ( e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite as $$y(x)=x\cos x+\frac12(\cos(2x)+1).$$ Thus you have terms that require simple characteristic roots $\pm 2i$, double roots $\pm i$ and again a simple root $0$. This makes for an order $7$ linear ODE with constant coefficients to contain all the linear and quadratic factors.